# Manipulate lynx --dump output to get only specific sections

Tags: grep, text-formatting

I'm trying to write a unit that will get me a word's definition from wordnik.com from CLI. Currently my code is:

```
function wordnik {           
     (( $+commands[lynx] )) || return 1             
lynx -nonumbers -dump https://www.wordnik.com/words/"$1"|grep -m 1 -A160 "Definitions" | less       
}
```

It's kind of working, but what I really want is to get only few sections from the page. The output should start from the Definitions section and end right before the Wordmap section. The filtering can be based on those patterns (Definitions, Wordmap).

Comment: Can you provide an example of an arg you would pass?

Comment: Any word. I already found a solution, it's way more basic than I thought.

Comment: I guess this is ok if you don't over-use it. Many sites don't like it when people use scripts to scrape their pages, especially when the site has gone to the trouble of providing a powerful API to allow programs to access their data. So if you go crazy getting words with your lynx-based script, don't be too surprised if your requests get blocked.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Wordnik, but from a quick browse of their developer page it appears that they have a particularly rich API, you just need to register and get an API key to use it. For a basic account, registration is free. And once you're registered you _can_ go crazy. :) Free accounts can do up to 15,000 calls per hour.

Comment: Unfortunately no one have developed any CLI tool. The closest I see is Emacs lisp client. I don't harvest the site or anything, I simply prefer to look up words without opening full featured GUI browser.I don't see the difference between lynx and firefox for that matter. Also, I don't see anything in the terms that forbids it and like you have seen, it seems they are good guys. I do understand where your comment comes from, though, in different situations it would make perfect sense.

Comment: I'm _sure_ casual use is fine, Dave's tux. In fact, using Lynx probably puts less demand on their server than Firefox, etc, since Lynx tends to not download images by default. It'd only be a problem if you were using your script to harvest _lots_ more stuff than what a human normally would do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply using the following instead of `grep` does the work:

```
sed -n "/Definition/,/Wordmap/p"
```

Comment: Really simple solution is probably good enough, but it prints the line that contains `Wordmap`, when the OP wants to stop printing before that.

Comment: It's good enough for me, but you are welcome to improve it. Another nice improvement would be to clean some of junk from the output. But even as it is the unit is extremely useful for me.